# C++/Qt Multiline strings; also, multiple queries

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Two [hopefully] quick questions regarding C++/Qt. Is the following proper for writing a string on multiple lines?

```
QString strQuery;
strQuery="\
         CREATE TABLE foo\
             (bar integer primary key,\
             baz varchar(20))";
```

I believe this is right, but in Qt Creator it doesn't highlight as though it is one big string.

Secondly, will QSqlQuery.exec() run multiple queries in a single execution or does each query need to be run through exec()? For example, I'm trying something like:

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString strQuery;
strQuery="\
         CREATE TABLE foo \
             (bar integer primary key,\
             baz varchar(10));\
        CREATE TABLE herp\
             (de integer primary key, \
             derp varchar(10))";
query.exec(strQuery);
```

From what I can see, only that first table is being created. I don't know if this is related to my multiline string, to my database type (SQLite), or just QSqlQuery in general.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that will be the right way:

```
QString strQuery;
strQuery="CREATE TABLE foo " \
         "(bar integer primary key, " \
         "baz varchar(20));";
// with this style `strQuery` will be single line, like "CREATE TABLE foo (bar integer primary key, baz varchar(20));"
```

---

```
QSqlQuery query;

QString strQuery;
strQuery="CREATE TABLE foo " \
         "(bar integer primary key, " \
         "baz varchar(10));"
query.exec(strQuery);

strQuery="CREATE TABLE herp " \
         "(de integer primary key, " \
         "derp varchar(10))";
query.exec(strQuery);
```

Comment: No need to escape the linefeeds with \. It's just whitespace and the C/C++ preprocessor automatically concatenates "string" "literals" with only whitespace in between.

Comment: I'd really like to be able to run multiple queries without having to do it as you've shown. SQLite seems to be capable of running multiple queries in a single execution, but I can't seem to get it to work from QSqlQuery::exec. I'll hold out a bit on this and hope someone can explain what I'm looking for; otherwise I'll mark your answer correct.